# Powershell gwmi for other users

Tags: powershell, wmi

I am trying to collect user profile information for users on a machine and I was wondering if I could get it with gwmi. Here is how I get printers for the current user:`Get-WmiObject win32_printer`. How can I get the same info for the user "Test" on the same machine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it happens, I can't sleep, so I came up with these 2 functions:

```psh
function Get-UserSid {
[CmdletBinding()]
param(
    [Parameter(
        ParameterSetName='NTAccount',
        Mandatory=$true,
        ValueFromPipeline=$true,
        Position=0
    )]
    [System.Security.Principal.NTAccount]
    $Identity ,

    [Parameter(
        ParameterSetName='DomainAndUser',
        Mandatory=$true
    )]
    [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
    [ValidatePattern('^[^\\]+$')]
    [String]
    $Domain ,

    [Parameter(
        ParameterSetName='DomainAndUser',
        Mandatory=$true
    )]
    [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
    [ValidatePattern('^[^\\]+$')]
    [String]
    $User
)

    Begin {
        if ($PSCmdlet.ParameterSetName -eq 'DomainAndUser') {
            $Identity = New-Object System.Security.Principal.NTAccount -ArgumentList $Domain,$User
        }
    }

    Process {
        $Identity.Translate([System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier])
    }
}

function Get-PrinterNameByUser {
[CmdletBinding(DefaultParameterSetName='Ambiguous')]
param(
    [Parameter(
        ParameterSetName='ByAccount',
        Mandatory=$true
    )]
    [System.Security.Principal.NTAccount]
    $Account ,

    [Parameter(
        ParameterSetName='BySID',
        Mandatory=$true
    )]
    [System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier]
    $SID ,

    [Parameter(
        ParameterSetName='Ambiguous',
        Mandatory=$true,
        Position=0,
        ValueFromPipeline=$true
    )]
    [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
    [String]
    $Identity
)

    Begin {
        Write-Verbose "Parameter Set Name: $($PSCmdlet.ParameterSetName)"
        if ($PSCmdlet.ParameterSetName -eq 'ByAccount') {
            $SID = $Account | Get-UserSid
        }
    }

    Process {
        if ($PSCmdlet.ParameterSetName -eq 'Ambiguous') {
            try {
                $SID = [System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier]$Identity
            } catch [System.InvalidCastException] {
                $Account = [System.Security.Principal.NTAccount]$Identity
                $SID = $Account | Get-UserSid
            }
        }
        Get-ChildItem -Path "Registry::\HKEY_Users\$($SID.Value)\Printers" | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Property -Unique
    }    

}
```

## Usage

```psh
Get-PrinterNameByUser Test
Get-PrinterNameByUser 'domain\test'
Get-PrinterNameByUser 'S-1-S-21-65454546-516413534-4444'
```

All of those could be piped as well:

```psh
'Test' | Get-PrinterNameByUser
'domain\test' | Get-PrinterNameByUser
'S-1-S-21-65454546-516413534-4444' | Get-PrinterNameByUser

'S-1-S-21-65454546-516413534-4444','user1','machine\user2','domain\user3' | Get-PrinterNameByUser
```

## Explanation

In the registry at `HKU\S-ID-HERE\Printers` there are some keys with properties. The property names are the printers. I wasn't able to test this on enough machines, so I wasn't certain which key(s) I should check, and whether they would be different depending on whether it was a local or network printer, etc., so I'm just getting the properties from all the keys and returning the unique ones.

The helper function `Get-UserSid` just provides a convenient way to get a SID from a user name.

Most of `Get-PrinterNameByUser` is just code to figure out what you've given it and translate it at needed. The meat of it that returns what you want is just the one line:

```psh
Get-ChildItem -Path "Registry::\HKEY_Users\$($SID.Value)\Printers" | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Property -Unique
```

Comment: This is fantastic! Thank you!